# Issue with fixed menu at top of window

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a menu that is added to the top of the page when a user selects an element on screen.

I have given it a higher `z-index`, but it still causes the page to scroll down a bit when an element is clicked.

Any ideas as to how to get around this?

Comment: pls post your menu code or site link

Comment: I don't get the link between z-index and scroll. Can you make a jsfiddle ? ( http://jsfiddle.net/ )

Comment: please post your code or demo.......

Comment: hey @Phil we want to see the code how are you trying than we will able to tell you the solution once we will see your code.......

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is in a lot of locations as it is a mobile site, we are using backbone.js and I'm trying to sort the code now so that you guys can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix the issue.

Because the element was being repositioned, it was being taken out of the document flow. This caused the page to jump upwards whenever this happened.

I fixed it by adding a container element with the same height as the element that is moved so now the jump does not happen because there is an element taking up the space vacated by the moved item.